# Not able to point GCC specific version

Tags: gcc, gcc8

I followed these steps for installing a gcc 8.4 version on a custom folder (--prefix = /FOLDER/)

https://www.hongliangjie.com/2012/07/20/how-to-install-gcc-higher-version-in-alternative-directory/

But I'm not able to use the new gcc 8.4. Everywhere I do 'gcc -v' I get gcc version 4.8.
I've tried also in /FOLDER/, /FOLDER/bin but no way. Neither 'gcc-8'

I'm working on my pivate space on a cluter via 'ssh', so no root permission.

I saw previous question but using

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/FOLDER/libexec/gcc/powerpc64le-unknown-linux-gnu/8.4.0

not working.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Either you call this `gcc` with an absolute path,

```
/FOLDER/bin/gcc --version
```

or you add its location to your PATH:

```
export PATH=/FOLDER/bin:$PATH
gcc --version
```

Unix does not add the current directory to PATH as Windows does, so to run the new `gcc` from `/FOLDER/bin` you'd have to specify to search from the current location:

```
cd /FOLDER/bin
./gcc --version
```

Comment: Many thanks! It was so easy but also kind of weird :D